# Django app deploy to Heroku, Application Error,

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am struggling to get my Django 1.10 app deployed to Heroku. Just as a preface, I am using Pycharm and had to rename my project at one point, but it refactored and changed the name in all places so I'm hoping that's not related to the issue. When I push this site to Heroku, I get an application error.

**Error messages**

In the Heroku app error log, I see:

```
2017-01-13T22:04:48.911324+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=secret-anchorage-68558.herokuapp.com request_id=71351a21-2264-4ca7-ad0a-1ae110d72ca7 fwd="162.247.89.174" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-01-13T22:04:49.334411+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=secret-anchorage-68558.herokuapp.com request_id=bf22a256-8780-49ed-8820-c8112833121c fwd="162.247.89.174" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

It once worked locally on my computer, but now when I try to run the app I get:

```
python3 manage.py runserver

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f278bc6ea60>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
autoreload.raise_last_exception()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
six.reraise(*_exception)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 116, in create
mod = import_module(mod_path)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'homelibrary.apps'
```

And when I try to push to Heroku:

```
git push heroku master

Counting objects: 308, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (122/122), done.
Writing objects: 100% (308/308), 111.03 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 308 (delta 170), reused 308 (delta 170)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.5.2
remote:      $ pip install -r requirements.txt
remote:        Collecting dj-database-url==0.4.2 (from -r      /tmp/build_6409be14e6f6fb2a7cd364b66c5920b7/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading dj_database_url-0.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting Django==1.10.5 (from -r /tmp/build_6409be14e6f6fb2a7cd364b66c5920b7/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Downloading Django-1.10.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.8MB)
remote:        Collecting gunicorn==19.6.0 (from -r /tmp/build_6409be14e6f6fb2a7cd364b66c5920b7/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Downloading gunicorn-19.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (114kB)
remote:        Collecting psycopg2==2.6.2 (from -r /tmp/build_6409be14e6f6fb2a7cd364b66c5920b7/requirements.txt (line 4))
remote:          Downloading psycopg2-2.6.2.tar.gz (376kB)
remote:        Collecting whitenoise==3.2.3 (from -r /tmp/build_6409be14e6f6fb2a7cd364b66c5920b7/requirements.txt (line 5))
remote:          Downloading whitenoise-3.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Installing collected packages: dj-database-url, Django,    gunicorn, psycopg2, whitenoise
remote:          Running setup.py install for psycopg2: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for psycopg2: finished with status 'done'
remote:        Successfully installed Django-1.10.5 dj-database-url-0.4.2 gunicorn-19.6.0 psycopg2-2.6.2 whitenoise-3.2.3
remote: 
remote:      $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
remote:            django.setup()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
remote:            apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
remote:            app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 116, in create
remote:            mod = import_module(mod_path)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in   import_module
remote:            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:        ImportError: No module named 'homelibrary.apps'
remote: 
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote: 
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote: 
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote: 
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to secret-anchorage-68558.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/secret-anchorage-68558.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/secret-anchorage-68558.git'
```

I have tried to disable the COLLECTSTATIC with

```
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=0
```

which seemed hopefull. It allows me to push my code to Heroku, but then when I try to

```
heroku run python3 manage.py migrate
```

or

```
heroku open
```

I get the same sort of error as previously and it doesn't appear online.

**Project structure**

```
---homelibrary
   ---catalog
      ---migrations
      ---static
         ---css
         ---images
            favicon.ico
      ---templates
      __init__.py
      admin.py
      apps.py
      forms.py
      models.py
      tests.py
      urls.py
      views.py
   ---homelibrary
      __init__.py
      settings.py
      urls.py
      wsgi.py
  ---templates (for generic, cross-site forms)
  ---venv
  .gitignore.txt
  db.sqlite3
  LICENSE
  manage.py
  Procfile
  README.md
  requirements.txt
  runtime.txt
```

**Requirements.txt**

```
dj-database-url==0.4.2
Django==1.10.5
gunicorn==19.6.0
psycopg2==2.6.2
whitenoise==3.2.3
```

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn homelibrary.wsgi --log-file -
```

**homelibrary/wsgi.py**

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "homelibrary.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

**homelibrary/settings.py**

```
import os
import dj_database_url

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY', 'My key')

DEBUG = bool(os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', False))

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'homelibrary.apps.CatalogConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'homelibrary.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['./templates',],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'homelibrary.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    'NAME':   'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator' ,
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
```

]

```
 LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

 TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'

 USE_I18N = True

 USE_L10N = True

 USE_TZ = True

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your `INSTALLED_APPS` with this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'catalog',
]
```

And there are some more mistake that you will face after

1. If your `DEBUG` in production is set to `False` then you need to change `ALLOWED_HOSTS=[]` 
   to `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`
2. Add in `settings.py` file

   `STATICFILES_STORAGE='whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'`

If it does not work then do one more stuff, look at step 8 and 9 [here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/68sc3ihna7qdaiu/test.py?dl=0)

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful in solving the static files issue.

Comment: I have a similar issue but the solution here didnt woek for me. Can you help look at it please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63465541/django-vuejs-app-deployed-to-heroku-showing-application-error-on-page